# How to find the next sequence number in oracle string field

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g, sql-view

I have a database table with document names stored as a VARCHAR and I need a way to figure out what the lowest available sequence number is. There are many gaps.

```
name          partial    seq
A-B-C-0001    A-B-C-     0001
A-B-C-0017    A-B-C-     0017
```

In the above example, it would be 0002.

The distinct name values total 227,705. The number of "partial" combinations is quite large A=150, B=218, C=52 so 1,700,400 potential combinations.

I found a way to iterate through from min to max per distinct value and list all the "missing" (aka available) values, but this seems inefficient given we are not using anywhere close to the max potential partial combinations (10,536 out of 1,700,400).

I'd rather have a table based on existing data with a partial value, it's next available sequence value, and a non-existent partial means 0001.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, you can try this:

```
select coalesce(min(to_number(seq)), 0) + 1
from t
where partial = 'A-B-C-' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.partial = t.partial and
                        to_number(T2.seq) = to_number(t.seq) + 1
                 );
```

EDIT:

For all partials you need a `group by`:

You can use `to_char()` to convert it back to a character, if necessary.

```
select partial, coalesce(min(to_number(seq)), 0) + 1
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.partial = t.partial and
                        to_number(T2.seq) = to_number(t.seq) + 1
                 )
group by partial;
```

Comment: that seems to work for the sample partial value I gave it. So can I just remove that part and it should do all of them?